# How to add item to an object in php

Tags: php, object, php-7

I have a nested object which is generated by a base data in a `function`. the data generated is several `levels` deep (`data_tree`)

To enter each `children` I use a `recursive function`.

**What I want is to `add` the data of the `children2` item to `children` and `remove children2`**

Next I show the `data_tree` in `JSON` format to get an idea of ​​how the `structure` is. remember that the data_tree is an `object`

```
{ 
"data_tree": [
                        {
                            "code":"PE",
                            "country":"Peruvian",
                            "language" :"spanish",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "code": "DEP1" , 
                                    "region":"Tumbes",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "code": "PRO1",
                                            "province":"Contralmirante Villar"
                                        }
                                    ],
                                    "children2": [
                                        {
                                            "code": "PRO2",
                                            "province":"Zarumilla "
                                        }
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "DEP2" ,
                                    "region":"Piura",
                                    "children": [],
                                    "children2": [
                                        {
                                            "code": "PRO4",
                                            "province" :"Paita"
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "code": "PRO5",
                                            "province":"Sullana"
                                        }
                                    ]
                                    
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "DEP3" ,
                                    "region":"Lambayeque"
                                }
                    
                            ],
                            "children2":[
                                {
                                    "code": "DEP4" ,
                                    "region":"La Libertad"
                                    
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "DEP5" ,
                                    "region":"Lima"
                                    
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                "code":"EC"
                            "country":"Ecuador",
                            "language" :"spanish",
                            "children":[
                                {
                                    "code": "4" ,
                                    "province":"Quito"
                                },
                                {
                                    "code": "5" ,
                                    "province":"Guayaquil"
                                }
                            ],
                            "children2":[]
                        }
                    ]
}
```

the `recursive function` i use is: if it has children it keeps iterating.

```
$traverse = function ($data_tree) use (&$traverse) {
    
                    foreach ($data_tree as &$node) { 
                        if (empty($node->children)) { //if the children is empty
                            unset($node->children); //I remove the children to add it with the data of children2
                            $node->children =$node->children2; 
                            unset($node->children2);//I delete children2
                        }else{

                           //in case I have data, how do I add the data from dechildren2 to children?
                            
                        }   

                        $traverse($node->children);
                    }
                };
    
$traverse($data_tree);
    
return $data_tree;
```

Answer (score 1):

All problem solved using json decode mean in associative array

```
$data_json='[{"children":[],"children2":[{"children":[],"children2":[{"code":"PRO1","children":[],"children2":[{"code":"PRO1"}]}]}]},{"children":[],"children2":[{"children":[{"code":"PRO1","children":[],"children2":[{"code":"PRO1"}]}]}]}]';


//$data_tree=;

$data_tree =json_decode($data_json,true);
// var_dump($data_tree);
$traverse = function (&$data_tree) use (&$traverse) {
    
  foreach ($data_tree as &$node) { 
    // var_dump($node);
      if (empty($node['children']) && !empty($node['children2'])) { //if the children is empty
        // var_dump($node);
          $node['children'] =$node['children2']; 
          unset($node['children2']);//I delete children2
      }else{

         //in case I have data, how do I add the data from dechildren2 to children?
          
      }   
      if(isset($node['children'])){
        $traverse($node['children']);
      } 
      if(isset($node['children2'])){
        $traverse($node['children2']);
      }
  }
};

$traverse($data_tree);
```

Output

```
[{"children":[{"children":[{"code":"PRO1","children":[{"code":"PRO1"}]}]}]},{"children":[{"children":[{"code":"PRO1","children":[{"code":"PRO1"}]}]}]}]
```